# Can't get release apk to run on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've migrated from Eclipse on one Windows machine to Android Studio on a new Ubuntu machine. I'm struggling with AS. I've managed to copy a project across with ftp and have managed to run the debug version on an emulator on the Ubuntu machine. The release version which I have signed exists in the same place as the debug apk. When I select release as the build variant it wo't run saying:
The apk for your currently selected variant (app-release-unsigned.apk) is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for ..
There is no such file below my project home directory, yet both the signed apks do exist

/home/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/GridMaps2.8/app/app-release.apk
/home/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/GridMaps2.8/app/app-debug.apk

My app gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debugFromAdventPC {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
            storeFile file('/home/nick/AndroidStudioKeystores/FromAdventPC/debug.keystore')
        }
        releaseFromAdventPC {
            keyAlias 'release_alias'
            keyPassword 'deleted'
            storeFile file('/home/nick/AndroidStudioKeystores/FromAdventPC/my-release-key.keystore')
            storePassword 'deleted'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:18'
    //compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "deleted"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need the signing file you signed the first files with. In your case : /home/nick/AndroidStudioKeystores/FromAdventPC/my-release-key.keystore

Comment: I know I have that. I signed the release apk with it. The signed release apk exists in  the app folder. Now an unsigned versiion keeps getting built in app/build/outputs/apk. Don't know why and don't know what to edit to make it work.

Comment: add signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseFromAdventPC to the buildTypes-> release. Also make sure you are building release variant

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are clicking on the green 'run' button in Android Studio.  AS then dutifully tries to build and create a program to run.  Which isn't really what you want.  You want to test your release APK?  Right?
To test your release APK:

1. Connect a phone to your computer with a USB cable.
2. Go to whatever file explorer software you are using on your Ubuntu machine.
3. Drag and drop your release APK to the phone, or ftp it over if your software can't handle that.  Or you can try doing a command line move.
4. Use file manager software on your phone to locate the release APK file and click on it.  It will unpack and install itself.  Answer any questions as needed.

If you make changes you will have to uninstall the app from your phone, build the signed release APK again and do the copying and installation stuff all over again.

If you just wanted to edit your app on the Ubuntu machine in Android Studio, you need to move over all the original files.  Eclipse should have an export function to help with that.

Hope that helps.